# How to do request/response with a consumer

Tags: c#, masstransit

On the [Request/Respond page in the documentation](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/request.html) it shows a response like this

```
Bus.Initialize(sbc => { 
   sbc.UseMsmq(); 
   sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient(); 
   sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/message_responder"); 
   sbc.Subscribe(subs=> { 
     subs.Handler<BasicRequest>( (cxt, msg )=> { 
       cxt.Respond(new BasicResponse{Text = "RESP"+msg.Text}); 
     }); 
   });
})
```

In my application I'm using Consumers rather than Handlers (because I need dependency injection via Autofac) so my consumer looks like this

```
public class DoctorImporter : Consumes<ImportDoctorCommand>.For<Guid>
{
    public void Consume(ImportDoctorCommand cmd) {
        foo.DoStuff();
        var ev = new ImportDoctorCommand.Occurred() { CorrelationId = cmd.CorrelationId };
        bus.Publish(ev);
    }
    readonly IServiceBus bus;
    readonly Foo foo;
    public DoctorImporter(IServiceBus bus, Foo foo) {
        this.bus = bus;
        this.foo = foo;
    }
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; private set; }
}
```

but this doesn't work because it seems like I need `.Respond()` rather than `.Publish()` and there's no `.Respond()` on `IServiceBus`.

So how do I do request/response from a consumer?

Comment: Replied elsewhere, but the sample is here: https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-RequestResponse

Comment: I see, thanks @ChrisPatterson that's different from what even I was doing. I notice the sample isn't doing correlated messages - won't something listening for the response potentially pick up responses for other instances of the came event? The whole concept of correlation and how to do it is really confusing.

Comment: Also @ChrisPatterson I assumed you meant that youreplied [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/masstransit-discuss/c8RPHMIFsC8/yhowN0XMAQAJ) but I don't see a reply?

Comment: Consumes<For> is long dead, and completely unnecessary for request/response.

Comment: This is the old MT way to do it, prior to v3: http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/request.html